# how to put footer inside rectangle

Tags: reporting-services

How can I put a "footer" inside a rectangle, that is always at the bottom of the rectangle, but where the other content of the rectangle (a tablix) pushes down the footer when that content becomes too big for the rectangle?

simple representation:

```
-------------------
| tablix row 1    |
| tablix row 2    |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
| footer          |
-------------------

-------------------
| tablix row 1    |
| tablix row 2    |
| tablix row 3    |
| tablix row 4    |
| tablix row 5    |
| tablix row 6    |
| tablix row 7    |
| tablix row 8    |
|                 |
| footer          |
-------------------

-------------------
| tablix row 1    |
| tablix row 2    |
| tablix row 3    |
| tablix row 4    |
| tablix row 5    |
| tablix row 6    |
| tablix row 7    |
| tablix row 8    |
| tablix row 9    |
| tablix row 10   |
| tablix row 11   |
| tablix row 12   |
| tablix row 13   |
| footer          |
-------------------
```

Comment: I've not tested this but try to create a large rectangle. Inside that put your tablix and the 'footer' rectangle. Then set the report property `Consume Container Whitespace` to `True`

Comment: @AlanSchofield, that definitely is the way to go I think. I tried it and it behaves quite good. I still need to make some other adjustmenst, since this rectangle is part of a bigger report